# Does bc not limit a variable's scope?

Tags: scope, global-variables, bc

Define the function in [basic calculator bc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/html_mono/bc.html) as

```
define void f () { test=42; print "all done\n"; }
```

I'd have thought the value of `test` would be limited to the scope of the function `f`, but no, `test` equals 42 globally. Is there no way to limit the scope of variables in bc functions? I.e. is there are way to define local variables in bc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify an `AUTO_LIST` in your function definition. From the [bc manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/text/bc.txt),

> ```
> `define' NAME `(' PARAMETERS `)' `{' NEWLINE
>     AUTO_LIST   STATEMENT_LIST `}'
>
> [...]
>
>
> The AUTO_LIST is an optional list of variables that are for "local"
> use.  The syntax of the auto list (if present) is "`auto' NAME, ... ;".
> (The semicolon is optional.)  Each NAME is the name of an auto
> variable.  Arrays may be specified by using the same notation as used
> in parameters.  These variables have their values pushed onto a stack
> at the start of the function.  The variables are then initialized to
> zero and used throughout the execution of the function.  At function
> exit, these variables are popped so that the original value (at the
> time of the function call) of these variables are restored.  The
> parameters are really auto variables that are initialized to a value
> provided in the function call.  Auto variables are different than
> traditional local variables because if function A calls function B, B
> may access function A's auto variables by just using the same name,
> unless function B has called them auto variables.  Due to the fact that
> auto variables and parameters are pushed onto a stack, `bc' supports
> recursive functions.
> ```

So to keep the `test` variable "local" in your function, you'd use

```
define void f () { auto test; test=42; print "all done\n"; }
```